# I need to assign a value to a variable in some method as beforeRender, as I do?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I need to assign a value to a variable in some method as beforeRender, as I do? 
(Sails.js v0.11.0)

Example CakePHP:

```
public function beforeRender(){
  ...
}
```

Example Rails:

```
before_render : ....
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Basicly everything in Action method is executed before render. Or you need code that is executed for all actions the same way in certain controller? use policy for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set locals in many places. It depends on your use case.

If the variable is different for each action, then you can place it inside the action calling the view.

If the variable is different for each request, then you can place it in a policy to set locals.

If the variable is static for a single route, you can put it in your routes.

If the variable is static for an application, then you can place in many places.

You can use Locals or Globals in your rendered view, which means any services you creates (even static objects) can be used inside your renderedViews

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Views/Locals.html
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Globals

Comment: I need set totalCustomers for all views after login

Now:

<code>
../api/controllers/CustomerController.js

...
    main: function(req, res){
        var totalCustomers = 0;
        Customer.count().exec(function totalCustomers(err, total){
        totalCustomers = parseInt(total);
        return res.view(null, { totalCustomers: totalCustomers });
});
    }
....
</code>

for each action.

but this is not good. I need set totalCustomers for all views, get Customers.count()... and set value for use in view

in CakePHP, Ruby on Rails have:

beforeRender () { ..... } and beforeFilter () { ..... }

Comment: the closest thing Sails has to beforeRender() out of the box is the policy. You should check that out. However, running that query before every view is not very efficient. You should put that into a callback on the customer model, then set that variable on the sails scope. This scope is available to your view automatically.

Comment: Exactly, beforeFind: function (values, cb) { values.totalCustomers = 45 } should be a function, or :  attribute: function () {return '45'}

As I can do this now?